# select only one of the identical rows (specific) between two tables in a union

Tags: mysql, union

i have have two identical tables

lets call them t1 and t2

and i want to show data from both of them  BUT they may have identical rows (lets say these rows have the same `id` )

in that case i only want to get the row from table 1 and ignore the one from second table .

so

```
SELECT column_name(s) FROM t1 UNION SELECT column_name(s) FROM t2
```

but how should i handle duplicates ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM t1
UNION
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM t2 
where not exists (select 1
                  from t1
                  where t1.col1 = t2.col1 and t1.col2 = t2.col2 and . . .
                 )
```

Answer (score 1):

you mean this ?

```
      select column1 , column2 from (
           SELECT column1 , column2 FROM t1 
           UNION 
           SELECT column1 , column2 FROM t2 
       )t
       group by column1
```

you will have distinct column1 here

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove duplicates from a SELECT result set, you could use the `DISTINCT` clause with a sub-query

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM (SELECT value FROM t1 UNION SELECT value FROM t2) AS S
```

Or better, you might use the [`UNION DISTINCT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html) syntax:

```
SELECT value FROM t1 UNION DISTINCT SELECT value FROM t2;
```

---

BTW, for `UNION` the default is `UNION DISTINCT` (whereas for `SELECT`, `SELECT ALL` is the default), so this could be rewritten as:

```
-- without specifier UNION is implicitly DISTINCT
SELECT value FROM t1 UNION SELECT value FROM t2;
```

... which is in fact the query you proposed. What was wrong with that? It works with my test set: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d4812/1

---

Maybe a [sqlfeedle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) with your actual table content might help to provide a better answer.